# Apache TIKA: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: XML_WRITE_EXC

Tags: tika-server

Apacke Tika 1.24.

Tika runs in server mode as follows:

`java -Xmx3G -jar tika-server.jar -spawnChild --host=hostname.domain.com`

I'm observing the following error in Tika Server log. What could cause it?

```
rmeta/text (autodetecting type)
ERROR Problem with writing the data, class org.apache.tika.server.MetadataList, 
ContentType: application/json
WARN  Interceptor for {http://resource.server.tika.apache.org/}MetadataResource has 
thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException:
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException:
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.apache.tika.server.writer.MetadataListMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(
MetadataListMessageBodyWriter.java:64)
...
WARN  Interceptor for {http://resource.server.tika.apache.org/}
MetadataResource has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: XML_WRITE_EXC
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor.
handleMessage(JAXRSDefaultFaultOutInterceptor.java:106)
```